# CloudKit: Subscribe to another user's data

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, concept

I am just trying to understand the concept. How do apps like Twitter and Instagram inform users that someone who they are following has a new post?

I have an app that stores data in iCloud (right now it's in the private database). What I want to do is to let other users (only users that subscribe, or "follow", to changes) of the app get notifications when more entries in this database are created. Using shared database approach is not an option. I do not want to deal with the accepting invitation to view a record every time a new record is created.

Should I move all data to the public database and have a unique ID to identify each user and create subscriptions this way? Then how would I map these unique IDs with the users? (How would I know which records belong to whom?

I am not thinking of code right now, just the concept. Can someone please explain how to approach this?

Comment: The private database won't really meet your needs.  The private database lives in the user's own iCloud storage and you therefore need to go through the sharing invitation process for each record that you want to allow another user to access.  The public database exists in a shared iCloud storage (you get a free allowance based on the number of active users and then have to pay).  Twitter and Instagram use their own databases

Comment: You can just put everything in the public database. You can include a reference to each user in the main entries. You can create specific subscriptions based on each users requirements. Here's an example; https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/33/8/delivering-notifications-with-cloudkit-push-messages-ckquerysubscription